# How to toggle between 3 classes on hover js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an unordered list with 4 items inside.
On mouse hover it should grow to 100% of the ul's width, and all the 'noun hovered li' should  shrink to 0% width. 
When mouse leaves they all should go back to their initial state of 25% width.
Something like:

```
<ul id="menu2">
  <li class="color"></li>
  <li class="color"></li>
  <li class="color"></li>
  <li class="color"></li>
</ul>
```

css

```
#menu2{
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.color{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
float: left;
height: 110px;
margin-right: 0;
width: 25%;
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}

.stateHovered{
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    background-color: #FAA500;
}
.stateOff{
    width: 0;
}
```

The js

```
function addListeners(){
document.getElementById('menu2').children.addEventListener("mouseover", toggleClassFunction);
    function toggleClassFunction() {
        for(i = 0; i < menu2.length; i++) {
            if(menu2[i] !=this) {
                menu2[i].className = "stateOff";
            }else if(menu2[i] === this){
                menu2[i].className = "stateHovered";
            }else {
                menu2[i].className = "color";
                }
        }
    }   
}
window.addEventListener("load", addListeners);
```

the end result, doesn't work ..

Comment: You can achieve this with help of jQuery check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cxw4joe/)

Comment: If you don't which to use jQuery, i recommend using [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: A.J, I thought your solution as a good one, but the fact is that i have to change a whole lot off css on hovering and leaving the element.

I believe that JQuery is a good tool for animation, but it doesn't help much when you really need to force class changing.

Answer (score 0):

On "mouseover" set the classes to "stateOff" or "stateHovered" as needed. Then on "mouseout" set them back to "color". If you can use jQuery it's fairly straight forward, although I think you're probably going to want to fiddle with the CSS a bit:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu2 li').mouseover(function(){
        //Instead of trying to figure out who is who, just set them all to "stateOff"
        $('#menu2 li').attr('class','stateOff');
      
        //Then set "this" to "stateHovered".
        $(this).attr('class','stateHovered');
      
        //The browser won't render any changes until the script finishes running,
        //So you don't have to worry about "this" jumping back and forth between
        //two styles.
    });
    
    
    $('#menu2 li').mouseout(function(){
        $('#menu2 li').attr('class','color');
    });
});
```

```css
menu2{
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.color{
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
list-style: none;
float: left;
height: 110px;
margin-right: 0;
width: 25%;
background-color: blue;
cursor: pointer;
}

.stateHovered{
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 500ms ease-out;
    background-color: #FAA500;
}
.stateOff{
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu2">
  <li class="color">A</li>
  <li class="color">B</li>
  <li class="color">C</li>
  <li class="color">D</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Seamus. 
I've been trying to avoid JQuery, even though i've tryed it but unfortunately it doesn't do what i need.
Here's a JS fidlle illustrating what's happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/FroPT/zz83zxzd/9/

Comment: Yeah. I think it's just a CSS problem at this point. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/zz83zxzd/10/ All I did was to change the CSS so that you can verify that the script is properly switching between three styles. Is there an example out there that illustrates the desired effect?